# Django: Model Form "object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'"

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to make a search form for one of my classes. The model of the form is:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import CharField, ModelMultipleChoiceField, ModelChoiceField
from books.models import Book, Author, Category
 
class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    authors = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Author.objects.all(),required=False)    
    category = ModelChoiceField (queryset=Category.objects.all(),required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ["title"]
```

And the view I'm using is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from books.models import Book,Author
from books.forms import BookForm, SearchForm
from users.models import User
 
def search_book(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = SearchForm(request.POST)
            stitle = form.cleaned_data['title']
            sauthor = form.cleaned_data['author']
            scategory = form.cleaned_data['category']
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    return render_to_response("books/create.html", {
        "form": form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The form shows up fine, but when I submit it I get an error: `'SearchForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'`

I'm not sure what's going on, can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Why call `form = SearchForm(request.POST)` twice?

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen My comment says the same thing as the answer that was accepted as correct 10 years ago. The problem really is that the code should not call SearchForm a second time.

Comment: shouldn't you also do form.save() cause its a ModelForm?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

For some reason, you're re-instantiating the form after you check `is_valid()`. Forms only get a `cleaned_data` attribute when `is_valid()` has been called, and you haven't called it on this new, second instance.

Just get rid of the second `form = SearchForm(request.POST)` and all should be well.

Answer (score 12):

I would write the code like this:

```
def search_book(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        stitle = form.cleaned_data['title']
        sauthor = form.cleaned_data['author']
        scategory = form.cleaned_data['category']
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    return render_to_response("books/create.html", {
        "form": form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Pretty much like the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).

Comment: Well, that works! Does the definition location of form make that much of a difference?

Comment: I don't know what your problem was, but I think that calling `SearchForm(request.POST)` twice was not necessary. The rest is just window-dressing: I happen to like this way of folding the Form construction arguments so that you need only one call.

Comment: Or exactly what @Daniel Roseman said. If I were you, I'd select his as the preferred answer because he identifies the precise cause.

Answer (score 3):

**I was facing the same problem,**
**I changed the code like this**

```
 if request.method == "POST":
     form = forms.RegisterForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
             fname = form.cleaned_data.get('fname')
             lname = form.cleaned_data.get('lname')
             email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
             pass1 = form.cleaned_data.get('pass1')
             pass2 = form.cleaned_data.get('pass2')
```

Answer (score 2):

At times,  if we forget the

```
return self.cleaned_data
```

in the clean function of django forms, we will not have any data though the `form.is_valid()` will return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way the error

```
'MyForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

may show up is if you try to update an existing model instance without passing `request.POST` to the relevant subclass of `ModelForm`. For example, we get this error in the following case:

```py
a = Article.objects.get(id=1)
f = ArticleForm(instance=a)
f.save()                    # <--- 'MyForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

Changing it to the following

```py
a = Article.objects.get(id=1)
f = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=a)
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^  <--- must be passed
f.save()
```

resolves the error.