# 'AuthenticationForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: html, django

I override a custom django login by importing the AuthenticationForm and using the code below in my views.py but the only problem Im getting is that when i try to clean the form it always gives an error: **'AuthenticationForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'**. What should I do to resolve this problem?
Here is my views.py for overriding custom django login

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm 
def auth_login(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('/')

else:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        username = form.cleaned_data['username']

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_superuser:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('/dashboard')

            else:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('/')

        else:
            messages.error(request,'Username or password not correct')
            return redirect('/accounts/login')
        

    return render(request,'registration/login.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Model Form "object has no attribute 'cleaned\_data'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308527/django-model-form-object-has-no-attribute-cleaned-data)

Answer (score 0):

**instead of this:**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        username = form.cleaned_data['username']

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
```

**try this:**

```
 if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        username = form.cleaned_data['username']

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
```

I hope you may get this

Comment: It's `is_valid`, not `isvalid`.

Comment: It's just a typo

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.cleand_data['something']` before calling `.is_valid` method of form.

Solution:

```py
def dummy_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DummyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            # Rest of the code.
```